# Section 15.7 Random Parameters Linear Regression Model in Greene (2011)

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood

I'm currently reading Section 15.7 Random Parameters Linear Regression Model in Greene's textbook (Econometric Analysis, 7th Edition, 2011).

He derives the log likelihood (15-31, page 634) as

$$ \ln L_s = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln \left\{ \frac{1}{R} \sum_{r=1}^R \prod_{t=1}^{T_i} \frac{1}{\sigma_\varepsilon \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left[\frac{ (y_{it}- x_{it}'(\beta + \Lambda w_{it}))^2 }{2\sigma_\varepsilon^2}   \right]  \right\} $$

On page 635, he takes derivatives and claims that the result "after some manipulation" is:

$$ \frac{\partial \ln L_s}{\partial(\beta, \Lambda)} = \sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{1}{R} \sum_{r=1}^R \sum_{t=1}^{T_i} \frac{ (y_{it}- x_{it}'(\beta + \Lambda w_{it})) }{\sigma_\varepsilon^2} \begin{bmatrix} x_{it} \\ x_{it} \otimes w_{ir} \end{bmatrix}  = 0$$

I tried taking derivatives myself, and some terms involving the exponential function always remain. What is the "manipulation" that Greene has in mind in order to obtain his expression?

Thanks!